# How to return all values inside for loop in python mysql with parameterized query?

Tags: python, mysql

```py
@app.route("/book_list")
def book_list():
    if 'loggedin' in session:       
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM book limit 20")
        data = cursor.fetchall()

        for row in data:
            book_id= row["book_id"]
            cursor.execute("SELECT round(AVG(bk_rating),1) FROM `book_rating`  WHERE book_id = %s", (book_id,))
            avg=cursor.fetchone()
        return render_template('book_list.html',  data=data, avg=avg )

    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Comment: Can you please formulate a proper question? What do you want to achieve? What is your problem? Does your code not work? Or is it throwing errors?

Answer (score 0):

You need only one select statement, so that the assignment of the average in a for loop is not required.

```
@app.route("/book_list")
def book_list():
    if 'loggedin' in session:       
        cursor.execute("SELECT b.*,t1.avg1 FROM book b INNER JOIN (SELECT round(AVG(bk_rating),1) avg1,book_id FROM `book_rating` GROUP BY book_id) t1 ON b.book_id = t1.book_id LIMIT 20")
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        return render_template('book_list.html',  data=data)

    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

IF you want all bood, not only the ones which have ratings

```
@app.route("/book_list")
def book_list():
    if 'loggedin' in session:       
        cursor.execute("SELECT b.*,t1.avg1 FROM book b LEFTJOIN (SELECT round(AVG(bk_rating),1) avg1,book_id FROM `book_rating` GROUP BY book_id) t1 ON b.book_id = t1.book_id LIMIT 20")
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        return render_template('book_list.html',  data=data)

    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

You should think about an ORDER BY for your LIMIT even when you make it rand()

Comment: Thanks a lot. But, here one error unknown column in t1.book_id. I had made it - SELECT b.*,t1.avg1 FROM book b 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT round(AVG(bk_rating),1) avg1, book_id FROM `book_rating` GROUP BY book_id)
t1 ON b.book_id = t1.book_id LIMIT 20

Comment: Hi yes i forgot to add the column in the inner Select,. check the updated answer

Comment: Thanks your reply. But this answer only who are posted the book ratings not for all books. Becoz we have using group by value in book_rating table.

Comment: Thanks your reply. Already i have done this work its working perfect. But my doubt is second query (asked question in first time) output not return the increment for loop value only one row fetched but its display 20 times thats all. But this python program run in command mode it work perfectly. when pass the parameter to book_list.html their not increment the average rating answer. Kindly share your answer jinja template.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, avg(bk_rating) should only return 1 row for every book_id and this links to your main table as a new column, that is what you asked. If you wnat mior you have to make a new question, but thos tiome add some tables and data and show with the data you provied what answer you like to have.

Comment: @app.route("/book_list")
def book_list():
 if 'loggedin' in session:  
  cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM book limit 20")
  data = cursor.fetchall()
  for row in data:
   book_id= str(row[0])
   cursor.execute("SELECT round(AVG(bk_rating),1)  FROM `book_rating`  WHERE book_id ={}".format(book_id))
   avg=cursor.fetchone()
  return render_template('book_list.html',  data=data,avg=avg)
 return redirect(url_for('index'))

Comment: here second query (SELECT round(AVG(bk_rating),1) FROM book_rating WHERE book_id ={}".format(book_id)) returns the correct value. Here book_id fetch from the first query. Its working perfectly in python command line mode. When we pass the second query parameter like "avg", when we call the book_list.html not return the all values. Only one row fetched. My doubt is jinja render template not return the for loop values.